# Change wording of "Your flagging history"

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-abilities, flag-history, wording

When you are viewing another user's flags, the flagging history column on the right still reads "Your flagging history", as if you are viewing your own flags.

I suggest changing it to match the style of the title at the top (which reads `Flagged posts for %username%`), perhaps `%username%'s flagging history`.

Comment: To avoid confusion; you are talking about viewing another user's flags as a Moderator, right?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Correct. (I didn't tag it with moderator-tools because it didn't seem to be a *tool* to me. Didn't realize there was a moderator-abilities tag)

Comment: This bugs me every time I look at the flag history of another user

Comment: Life as a moderator must be *so hard.* I feel for you guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fair enough; that is a little misleading; fixed next build.